# The origin of the name homological equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, homology-cohomology, lie-derivative

Let

$$\dot{y} = Ay + \cdots \, ,$$

where the dots represent higher order terms in $y$. Make the change of variables $y \mapsto x - h(y)$, where $h$ is a vector valued polynomial of order $r$ in $y$. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-resonant, that is, if none of them can be expressed as a linear combination of the others, then the system above can be brought to the form

$$ \dot{x} = Ax + v(x) + \cdots \, ,$$

where the dots express terms of order higher than $r$ and

$$v(x) = \frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x} Ax - Ah(x) := L_A h(x) \, .$$

Then equation $L_A h = v$ is called *the homological equation associated to $h$* ($L_A$ can be seen as a Lie derivative). The possibility for such a linearisation is called the *Poincaré theorem*. The context is the one of [normal forms](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Normal_forms) for dynamical systems.

My question is: I know some objects in mathematics are named sort of randomly, but *homological* is a very, very specific name. I simply cannot associate the *homological equation* with *homology* (the one with classes, exact sequences, cohomology and Betti numbers). Is there a connection or is this name simply unfortunate?